# KeyError: 'ETag' while trying to load data from S3 to Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-s3, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

I Unload a file of 500 MB into S3 from Redshift, instead of saving into a single file in S3 it bifurcated into several chunks and now I am trying to access it from S3 to AWS Sagemaker. While trying to read the file using Pd.read_csv and dask.dataframe.read_csv I am getting Keyerror as 'ETag'

I'm a newbie to AWS, please do help me.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to download the file(s) to your notebook's local storage and read from there? Looks like a package version issue.
You can download multiple files by running `!aws s3 cp s3://bucket/prefix/ . --recursive` in your notebook cell.

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to import using a bucket name with /'s in it? The top level bucket is read in with

```
my_bucket = s3.Bucket("data-bucket-named")
```

and then the subfolders can be read in with:

```
subfolders= "subfolder1/subfolder2/subfolder3"
csvs = []
for object_summary in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=subfolders):
    key=object_summary.key
    if key.endswith(".csv"):
    csvs.append(key)
all_data = pd.DataFrame({})
for file in csvs:
    df = pd.read_csv(f's3://{"data-bucket-named"}/{file}')
    add_data = pd.concat([all_df, df])
```

Hope that helps.